# Django on tornado: serve static files

Tags: python, django, tornado

I'm running a django app on tornado server with tornado.web.fallback

```
(r"/hello/(.*)", HelloHandler),
('.*', tornado.web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=wsgi_app)),
```

the problem is that django is not serving static files at `/static/` url even when `static_dirs` and `static_root` are added in `settigs.py`. I have added both `static_dirs and static_root` as same directory where all of my static files are present

Comment: Is this a production environment? do you have nginx or anything? how is your django urls file?